# what is the fastest way to replace all appearances of ... in strings by space? Java

Tags: java, string, replace, split

I have problem in my program. In my program a bottleneck is replacing and spliting String.
I need to get words to tab from String.

For example:

I have String: "This is Ala. Does Ala have a cat? Money-making cat."

I need to get a String tab[]
and results

```
tab[0]="This"<br>
tab[1]="is"<br>
tab[2]="Ala"    not "Ala."<br>
tab[3]="Does"<br>
....<br>
tab[7]="cat" not "cat?"<br>
tab[8]="Money"   not "Money-making"<br>
tab[9]="making"<br>
tab[10]="cat" not "cat."  <br>
```

The words cant have signs like ",./;!:?- etc. They can have only english letters.

Actually im doing this like that

```
s = s.replace(",", " ").replace("!", " ")....   ;

String [] tab = s.split("\\s+");
```

But this way is really slow. How can i do that faster? In Java Language.

Comment: Today I saw many questions related to fastest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split at one or more non-word characters:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\W+");
```

Note: Non-word characters mean anything other than `_`, letters and digits. If you only want lettes than you would have to go with [@Bailey S](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482239/738746)'s answer.

Comment: You could also use `String[] parts = str.split("\s+");` to break the string up at white spaces only.  Then you could iterate through the array returned, and run replaceAll on each token.

Answer (score 0):

You can use replaceAll.For example s.replaceAll("[?.,]","")